# Disable SVG mouseclick event using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I want to disable clicking on an SVG element using css:

```
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

When I get the SVG element using `$(".dasvg")`, the console shows that I have selected the element:

```
[
  <svg width=​"500" height=​"500" class=​"dasvg">​
  <defs>​…​</defs>​
  <defs>​…​</defs>​
  <path class=​"link dragline hidden" d=​"M0,0L0,0">​</path>​
  <g>​…​</g>​
  <g>​…​</g>​
  </svg>​
]
```

However, when I try to do something like `$(".dasvg").addClass("disabled")` or $(".dasvg")[0].addClass("disabled")`, the`disabled` class does not get appended to the element. Is there a way to disable SVG elements using CSS?

Comment: `$(".dasvg")[0]` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object -- `.addClass` won't work on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery's addClass doesn't work with SVG classes as jquery can't cope with SVG class attributes being animatable. Just use `$(".dasvg")[0].setAttribute("class", "disabled")` assuming that the element doesn't have any classses already.

Comment: $(".dasvg")[0].setAttribute("class", $(".dasvg")[0].attr('class') + " disabled") would work even if it already has classes

Answer (score 2):

You may put css inside svg tag:

```
<svg>​
    <!-- Insert here​ -->
    <style>
        .disabled {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    <style>
    <!-- The rest of the code -->
</svg>​
```